# GORM minSize constraint is ignored

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my Grails 3.3.5 app, I have the following domain classes

```
class Evidence {

    String customer
    static hasMany = [images: Image]

    static constraints = {
        images minSize: 1
    }
}

class Image {
    String url
    static belongsTo = [evidence: Evidence]
}
```

It seems the `minSize` constraint is being ignored, because if I execute

```
new Evidence(customer: 'test').save(failOnError: true)
```

the object is saved in the `evidence` table even though there are no images mapped to it.

Comment: See https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/1083

Comment: This seems more like a bug report than a question.  There is some discussion about the behavior at the link I provided above.

Comment: Seems you could also add `Set images = [] as Set` as an initializer, and it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to set `images minSize: 1, nullable: false` in order for this to work as I expected. There is some discussion of this issue at the links below:

- https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/2115
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grails-dev-discuss/evQx2tz-DxI